# nyroModal forcing a page redirection

Tags: jquery, issue-tracking, nyromodal

I have a contact form that is called using this:

```
<a id="modalContact" class="nyroModal" href="contact/index.php" title="Contacto"><img src="assets/img/page_flip.png" alt="" /></a>
```

and here's the javascript (jQuery) that is executed when the user clicks it:

```
$(function(){
    $('#modalContact').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).nyroModalManual({
            url: 'contact/index.php',
            height: 550,
            width: 335
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The thing is, that when someone clicks the link it opens the modal and before anything gets to load it automatically redirects the only thing that appears in the URL is a # and I really can't figure out why it's getting redirected. the code inside contact/index.php is a basic contact form the only different thing would be that it contains a reCAPTCHA which is actually what can be read in the status bar that seems to be eternally (as it never finishes) loading.

What could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

It might because of reCAPTCHA, when nyroModal read something out of same domain , it treat third party that why redirect.